# Directional Derivatives from Contour Map

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am to: Use the contour diagram of f to decide if the specified directional derivative is positive, negative, or approximately zero. My solutions are noted in parentheses for each. I'm not sure where I am going wrong here.

[image]

1. At the point (−1,1) in the direction of $\frac{(−i −j)}{\sqrt{2}}$ (zero)
2. At the point (0,2) in the direction of j (positive)
3. At the point (1,0) in the direction of −j (positive)
4. At the point (−2,2) in the direction of i (negative)
5. At the point (0,−2) in the direction of $\frac{(i −2j)}{\sqrt{5}}$ (positive)
6. At the point (−1,1) in the direction of $\frac{(−i +j)}{\sqrt{2}}$ (positive)

Comment: The first one I see is wrong is 3 (one thing to note is that the gradient points outwards from the center at all points except $(0,0)$). At the point $(1,0)$ the gradient points exactly to the right while the direction vector points downwards...this will yield a zero directional derivative as they are orthogonal